# How can I position my elements more efficiently to remove the excess space?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently very much a newcomer to Web development and have come across a problem with the excess space of my items.
[image]

```css
#article_home_header {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#img_home_headerBKG {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 75px;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

#PFP {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  color: #BFD7B4;
  display: block;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  color: #BFD7B4;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  font-family: 'hs_serif';
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav_home">
  <input id="search_nav" type="search" placeholder="Search..." pattern="[A-z][0-9]" required>
  <button id="b_nav_search">Search</button>
  <button id="b_nav_drawer"></button>
</nav>
<header id="headDisplay">
  <article id="article_home_header">
    <img id="img_home_headerBKG" src="/Res/img_PersonalWeb_headerbkg.jpg" />
    <img id="PFP" src="/Res/img_PersonalWeb_headerbkg.jpg" />
    <h1>Jalen Paul</h1>
  </article>
</header>
<article id="article_home_content">
  <section>
    <h3><b>About Me</b></h3>
    <h4> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
      desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </h4>
  </section>
</article>
```

What would be a recommended approach to handling this task of removing the excess space around the image and nav bar? any tips and tutorial links would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_body.asp):

> Most browsers will display the `<body>` element with the following
> default values:
>
> body {   display: block;   margin: 8px; }

Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

See the snippet below.

```css
/* Added */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#article_home_header {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}

#img_home_headerBKG {
  position: absolute;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 75px;
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

#PFP {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 175px;
  height: 175px;
  color: #BFD7B4;
  display: block;
  left: 45%;
  top: 45%;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 {
  color: #BFD7B4;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 40%;
  font-family: 'hs_serif';
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav_home">
  <input id="search_nav" type="search" placeholder="Search..." pattern="[A-z][0-9]" required>
  <button id="b_nav_search">Search</button>
  <button id="b_nav_drawer"></button>
</nav>
<header id="headDisplay">
  <article id="article_home_header">
    <img id="img_home_headerBKG" src="/Res/img_PersonalWeb_headerbkg.jpg" />
    <img id="PFP" src="/Res/img_PersonalWeb_headerbkg.jpg" />
    <h1>Jalen Paul</h1>
  </article>
</header>
<article id="article_home_content">
  <section>
    <h3><b>About Me</b></h3>
    <h4> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
      It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
      desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </h4>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: only `body {margin: 0 }` is needed. Html has no default margin

Comment: That seems to be the solution, I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you very much ill mark this as the correct solution.

Answer (score -1):

There some browser css default config. This will remove some of this default config.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: a global reset is not recommended. It requires all default margins to re-add again. It is way easier and cleaner to only reset the margin you want to reset. In this case the body margin. Of course, you can nuke the entire design and start rebuilding it but that is way more work then a simple solution.